# Compare multiple columns between two worksheets in an Excel spreadsheet and identify variances

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm a newbie in Excel and have a workbook that has 2 similar worksheets. Worksheet 1 (titled Master) is my master worksheet that has more data. Worksheet 2 (titled Slave) has the same columns.  However, data in both worksheets are in different rows (for instance, cell values in Master!A2 may exist in Slave, but on a different row).

I want to compare Master worksheet with Slave and identify discrepancies.  If it matches, show yes in an empty column in Master; if there are differences, indicate the variance in an empty column in Master.  Is that possible?

[Master Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCO27.png)

[Slave Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTxhC.png)

Comment: Write a VBA macro

Comment: Are you having trouble with the topics in the Related section down the right hand side of the page? Are you having trouble with this site's Search? Are you having trouble googling your problem?

Comment: I'm by no means an Excel guru so need assistance writing a VBA macro.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the data on master and slave have columns with same headers. Couldn't you filter 2 similar columns to sort A to Z and then it would all align. Then, on one of the tabs you can put =MasterA2=SlaveA2 and the output would be True or False.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks VeryNew2SQL.  This would work if the rows matched 1 to 1, but unfortunately they do not.  One dataset might appear on row 2 of Master, but appear in row 5 of Slave.  Plus Master has more data than Slave, Master has 692000 rows whereas Slave has 20000 rows.

Comment: gotcha. sorry. i will keep trying to solve. more to come.